# How to deserialize array of Joda-Time LocalDate to java.time LocalDate?

Tags: java, serialization, jodatime, java-time

Since recent migration to Java 10, we are also considering replacing [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) by [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes in our codebase. A big obstacle is handling the existing serialised Java objects which have array of Joda-Time (ex. `LocalDate`, `Period`) as fields.

The version of Joda-Time used in the project is a customised one, ie. we have complet control over it. I have tried to provide `readObject` implementation in Joda-Time `LocalDate` to let it return a Java `LocalDate`. But that doesn't work in case the LocalDates are contained in an array, where an `ArrayStoreException` is thrown from `readArray` method of `ObjectInputStream`, since the local version of LocalDate is the Java one.

```
// code taken from ObjectInputStream
Object array = null;
    Class<?> cl, ccl = null;
    if ((cl = desc.forClass()) != null) {
        ccl = cl.getComponentType(); // ccl is java LocalDate.class
        array = Array.newInstance(ccl, len);
}

...// intermediate code ignored

Object[] oa = (Object[]) array;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    oa[i] = readObject0(false); // ArrayStoreException thrown here, readObject0 returns a joda LocalDate
    handles.markDependency(arrayHandle, passHandle);
}
```

I even tried to subclass `ObjectInputStream` to let it resolve to a Java `LocalDate.class` in case it is deserialising a joda LocalDate. It doesn't work since JVM detects that the serialised LocalDate doesn't have same serialVersionUID with the resolved one (obviously true since Java LocalDate has different UID). In a straight forward thinking to break through, I have tried to make the two return a same UID by reflection and overriding `readClassDescriptor` of `ObjectInputStream`. But later there are new exceptions occurred. And what make things complicated is that Java time serialization is done by the Ser.class in an `Externalizable` way, different from joda time. And ObjectInputStream handles them differently. So now I got stuck in this way.

Before doing more hacking in subclassing ObjectInputStream, I want to hear from more people about your thoughts/experience on such problem, or technically how to deserialize changed version of array object. Btw, I heavily doubt if I am in a right way to solve the problem I am facing, that be able to read the existing serialized objects.

Sample code:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DemoObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private LocalDate[] dates;

    public DemoObject(LocalDate[] dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.asList(dates).toString();
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SerializationDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LocalDate[] dates = new LocalDate[2];
        for (int i=0; i<dates.length; i++) {
            dates[i] = new LocalDate().minusDays(i);
        }

        DemoObject demoObject = new DemoObject(dates);
        serialize(demoObject);
        deserialize(getSerialFileName(demoObject));
    }

    private static void serialize(Object demoObject) throws IOException {
        try(ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(getSerialFileName(demoObject)))) {
            out.writeObject(demoObject);
        }
    }

    private static Object deserialize(String fileName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
            Object demoObject = in.readObject();
            System.out.println(demoObject);
            return demoObject;
        }
    }
}
```

First run the above code to generate a ser file. Then comment the call to method `serialize(demoObject);` and replace joda LocalDate by java LocalDate. Run again the code you will get a ClassCastException saying that it is trying to convert org.joda.time.LocalDate to java.time.LocalDate. We can get around this by subclassing the ObjectInputStream and override the readObject method to return a java LocalDate in case deserializing the joda one.

```
public class DemoObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

    public DemoObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        super(in);
        enableResolveObject(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected final Object resolveObject(Object object) {
        if (object != null && object.getClass().equals(org.joda.time.LocalDate.class)) {
            org.joda.time.LocalDate date = (org.joda.time.LocalDate) object;
            return LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonthOfYear(), date.getDayOfMonth());
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

However, an ArrayStoreException will be thrown when constructing the deserialized array object.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.time.LocalDate
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at com.serialization.SerializationDemo.deserialize(SerializationDemo.java:51)
        at com.serialization.SerializationDemo.main(SerializationDemo.java:40)
```

How to get around such issue with array?

Comment: By the way, in the future, consider serializing your date-time values as text using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: @BasilBourque yeah that's a good point, thx. String makes things much easier than objects